# Yarn install with yarn.lock failed with `403 Forbidden`

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-lock.json

Our project depends on package A which depends on package B. Both A and B exists in a private registry.

Installing package A will update yarn.lock. With the updated yarn.lock, `yarn install` will fail with error

```
Package B Request failed \"403 Forbidden\"
```

However this error will disappear if we simply delete yarn.lock. What can we do to make `yarn install` work with yarn.lock?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!